# Culture unrelated code works differently when culture changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is my Controller (I have removed complete code for simplicity)

```
public IActionResult Settings(SettingsViewModel model, ICollection<IFormFile> file)
{
    ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.NormalizedUserName == User.Identity.Name.ToUpper());
    return View(model);
}
```

This is my routing:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{culture=fa-IR}/{controller=Names}/{action=GirlAndBoy}/{p1=A}/{p2=1}");
    });
```

The view works fine culture-wise and translate to all three('en-us','tr-tr','fa-ir') languages.

But the problem is, the user is logged in and in 'en-us' and 'fa-ir' the code works correctly but in 'tr-tr' `user` is null as the result of the following code:

```
    ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.NormalizedUserName == User.Identity.Name.ToUpper());
```

Please note that even when culture is 'tr-tr' trace shows that `User.Identity.Name.ToUpper()` has the correct value.

Comment: I changed `User.Identity.Name.ToUpper()` to`User.Identity.Name.Normalize()` and now it works correctly. My problem is solved but I still wonder what this has to do with culture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with how culture and strings relate and also capitalization across different cultures. This page is very relevant to this problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings#stringequals

> For nearly all Latin alphabets, including U.S. English, the character
>   "i" (\u0069) is the lowercase version of the character "I" (\u0049).
>   This casing rule quickly becomes the default for someone programming
>   in such a culture. However, the Turkish ("tr-TR") alphabet includes an
>   "I with a dot" character "İ" (\u0130), which is the capital version of
>   "i". Turkish also includes a lowercase "i without a dot" character,
>   "ı" (\u0131), which capitalizes to "I".

In this case, you may want to use normalization + string comparison using OrdinalIgnoreCase. This should resolve culture and capitalization issues.

```
var normalizedUserName = User.Identity.Name.Normalize();
ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => String.Equals(u.NormalizedUserName, normalizedUserName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnore​Case));
```